# Postgres DB table recovery

Tags: data-recovery, postgresql, pgadmin3

I was using PG Admin and modifying a table in my DB. I was actually adding two fields.

Once done, I hit the OK button and PG Admin hung up. I think this is the first time.

Now I cannot open that specific table through PG Admin. I'm not sure if this is corrupt.

How can I recover this or repair it?

Thanks!

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop version

EDIT: 
Each time I try to open it, PG Admin hangs and I have to force-quit it.

Comment: I would log in using `psql` and see what became of the table.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut Thanks for your input. I can login now using pgAdmin and also the changes I was making were also updated despite the crash. If I recall this is the first time PG ever crashed on my system.

Comment: And my problem is BACK! I cannot even right-click the table to select an option.

Comment: I think this is a bug on PGAdmin. It is ok now after a system restart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to get about it but here's what I did to fix the issue.

1. Open PGAdmin
2. Right click the table and from the menu select MAINTENANCE
3. Clicked on Vacuum and under vacuuming options I took full vacuum.

In addition, I did 'reset table statistics'.

Now it seems ok.